# Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type SharedDataModel found. A View.environmentObject may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, swiftui, observableobject

I have another project with almost identical code and it runs with no issues i'm not sure why it crashes. It build successfully then it crashes with Fatal error on the if statement line.

```
     if sharedData.likedAwards.isEmpty {
                        
                        Group {
                            Image("NoAwards")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .padding()
                                .padding(.top,35)
                        
                            Text("No awards yet")
                                .font(.custom(customFont, size: 25))
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            
                        
                        }
```

The Following Code is in SharedDataModel:

```
import SwiftUI

class SharedDataModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // Detail Award Data....
    @Published var detailAward: Award?
    @Published var showDetailAward: Bool = false
    
    // matched Geoemtry Effect from Search page...
    @Published var fromSearchPage: Bool = false
    
    // Liked Awards...
    @Published var likedAwards: [Award] = []
    
    
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 1):

use @StateObject var sharedData = SharedDataModel()  to create instances of your object on the view to be conform

```
struct ContentView : View {

@StateObject var sharedData = SharedDataModel()

var body: some View {
Vstack{
if sharedData.likedAwards.isEmpty {
                    
                    Group {
                        Image("NoAwards")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .padding()
                            .padding(.top,35)
                    
                        Text("No awards yet")
                            .font(.custom(customFont, size: 25))
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        
                    }

                    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this prevents the crash. I am now trying to display the MainPage when the application is launched. If the: if sharedData line is removed from ContentView the crash happens however I need the MainPage to appear. I'm struggling to make this happen without the app crashing. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I don’t know if you can share your code with GitHub or something. If you want me to help you

Comment: that sounds good thanks. I just set up my GitHub account. I assume I just publish repository and make it public?  My username is: Mxyb I just published the repository. Thanks a lot

Comment: there is nothing in your repo project

Comment: I published the repository on GitHub Desktop and when I go on the website it is there for me and says public. What do I need to do so that you can view it? Thanks

Comment: I don't use github desktop but yes you have to stay in public for me to have access to the repo

Comment: It's titled CollectionPageV1 and is public, is it working now?

Comment: I can see only your initial commit. You must do « git add . » git commit -m « message » and git push to your repo

Comment: If your are Twitter follow me @SrgAdr it will be more simple to send message

Comment: Okay thanks! I followed you on twitter